# VBA Creating an Excel .xlsm vs .xlsx

Tags: vba, excel

Hello thanks for reading my question, I have a Workbook with hidden templates and most of them are used as Excel .xlsx spreadsheet however one of them requires a module to be inserted for it to work. I thought simple enough just add a param to my function that creates the workbook.

It doesn't seem to work because i get an error "Error Number 1004 This extension can not be used with the selected file type. Change the file extension in the file name text box or select a different file type blabla"

```
Public Function gWrkBook(template As String, Optional wbMacro As Boolean) As Workbook
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Dim wsTemplate As Worksheet, wsSummary As Worksheet


Set wsTemplate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(template) '===== Create new workbook and copy template
wsTemplate.Visible = True
'
Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add                          'Create New file
wsTemplate.Copy Before:=wbNew.Sheets(1)            'Copy template to new workbook
                                                   'Rename sheet
On Error GoTo ErrSheetName
    wbNew.Sheets(1).Name = "SUMMARY"

Set wsSummary = wbNew.Sheets("SUMMARY")


wsTemplate.Visible = False '===== Clean up
Call gRemoveUnwanted("sheets", wbNew) 'Mod7 '==== Get SaveAs filename and save file


If wbMacro = True Then
    vFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(Filname, "Excel Macro-Enabled workbook(*.xlsm), *.xlsm", Title:="SaveAs Workbook Macro-Enabled")
Else
    vFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks, *.xlsx", Title:="SaveAs Workbook")
End If

On Error GoTo ErrFileName
    wbNew.SaveAs Filename:=vFileName

Set gWrkBook = wbNew 'must assign it this way?? not sure why R2

Exit Function

ErrSheetName:
NewSheetName = InputBox("Worksheet exists, try a different name." & vbCrLf & "Enter Sheet Name.")
Resume

ErrFileName:
MsgBox "Error Number " & _
        Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
        Error(Err) & vbCrLf & _
        "Try Again!", _
        vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, _
        "ERROR!"
vFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks, *.xls; *.xlsx", _
                                        Title:="SaveAs Workbook")
Resume

End Function
```

Comment: You need to add a`FileFormat` argument to the `SaveAs` function.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

`wbNew.SaveAs(Filename:=vFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled)`

For more information, please read documentation:

- [VBA SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185(v=office.15).aspx)
- [VBA File Format XlFileFormat Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx).

Comment: Thanks that worked great, posted the working code for others